# FileShare.ReadWrite in System.IO.Packaging

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.packaging

I am using System.IO.Packaging to work with Package files.

But it seems Package cannot open a file with read access providing FileShare.ReadWrite.
Here's the code :

```
 myPackage = Package.Open("fileName", FileMode.Open,  FileAccess.Read,  FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

When I try to load a file, the following exception is thrown:

Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in WindowsBase.dll

Additional information: Only FileShare.Read and FileShare.None are supported.

Is there anything that can be done to get this working? 
I need FileShare to be set to ReadWrite.

EDIT:
I am trying to work with a docx file in my code. I just want to be able to read the contents of the file without modifying it. In the meanwhile I also want it to be editable using Word. This is what I am trying to achieve. I have used DotNetZip's Ionic.Zip library with success for this purpose. But i encountered some errors while saving files using that. So I had to get back to System.IO.Packaging. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error makes perfect sense. Why would you need to write to an Archive while it's  being read?  The library just doesn't allow (support) that kind of concurrency.

Comment: Probably it does. But like I said in my question, I was able to do it using Ionic.Zip. But it has known issues that is critical to my other needs.

Comment: You should look for explicit promises that it will work. Because I don't see how one archive instance could prevent another from overwriting its internal files. They are not real files with OS protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you want to do this, but you can try specifying options on file stream directly like this:

```
using (var file = new FileStream(@"myfile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    var myPackage = Package.Open(file);
}
```

UPDATE to elaborate a bit more about when this might be useful. Suppose you try to do something like this:

```
using (var fs1 = new FileStream("myfile", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
using (var fs2 = new FileStream("myfile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
}
```

So first file is opened for writing, with FileShare = Read. Then there is another attempt to open file, for reading, again with FileShare = Read. This won't work, because if file has already been opened for write, any request with FileShare = read will fail. To make this work you have to do it like this:

```
using (var fs1 = new FileStream("myfile", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
using (var fs2 = new FileStream("myfile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
}
```

Here you request FileShare.ReadWrite which allows you to read file opened by fs1 for writing.

Now, if writing and reading the same file concurrently is a good idea is completely dependent of what you want to achieve and if you know what you are doing. In most cases it's not a good idea, but again it depends.

UPDATE 2. It's perfectly possible to use code above to achieve your goal (open .docx for reading while MS Word has it open for writing:

```
using (var file = new FileStream(@"my.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    var myPackage = Package.Open(file);
    // here do what you want with your .docx
}
```

Comment: And do you think this will be safe to use?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Updated post trying to answer to your question

Comment: Disposing the stream  renders the myPackage object useless.

Comment: Well that is just example, it's not necessary to dispose it. It is assumed that before you dispose it, you did what you want to with it.

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited the question providing more information about what I am looking to achieve.

Comment: The opening of the file is only the beginning. Circumventing a safety check does not solve the actual problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman as you see author has a perfectly reasonable problem - read .docx opened by MS Word application. And approach above does solve this problem. In many cases you can be quite sure user will not write (and save) to that word file while you are reading, or you may explicitly warn user to not do that. So, reading file opened for writing is not necessary "Circumventing a safety check".

Comment: Make sure to tell the user to disable the AutoSave feature.